# Get wordpress posts in categories via Ajax uisng Semantic UI API and tabs

Tags: ajax, wordpress, semantic-ui

I am trying to create tabs using semantic UI tabs and get content via an ajax call. I looked into the [documentation](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#retreiving-remote-content) but could't figure out a way to get the content from my wordpress site. 
I want to create tab titles with category name and load the posts of that category via ajax when user clicks the title. I don't know if this is possible with the semantic UI API,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call the wordpress api to get categories and put the category name, id and slug in a javascript object.

`http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/`

Then loop through the object and show titles.
Use the slug to call 
`wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[category_name]=uncategorized` to get posts from category

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using symantic ui as a separate instance (not wp theme) and want to get content from the wordpress site then you need a REST api and not ajax. You should follow @Gisha James advice.

But if you are using symantic ui in a wordpress theme, and you want content to be loaded from the same wordpress installation then its a bit tricker because you need to understand how wordpress handles ajax, which basically works on 'admin-ajax.php'.

Here is a very simple implimentation taken from another [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249929/load-content-in-a-div-with-ajax/249932).

```
// Footer or spearate js file    
    <script>
    $(".post-link").click(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel"); //this is the post id
        $("#post-container").html("content loading");
        $.ajax({
            url: myapiurl.ajax_url,
            type: 'post|get|put',
            data: {
                action: 'my_php_function_name',
                post_id: post_id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // What I have to do...
            },
            fail: {
                // What I have to do...
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    </script> 

// Function.php
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_ajax_scripts' );
function my_ajax_scripts() {
    wp_localize_script( 'ajaxRequestId', 'myapiurl', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function my_php_function_name() {
    // What I have to do...
}
```